# Códigos ANSI não estão funcionando em uma QTextEdit

Tags: python

Então, eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Python e estou usando PyQt5.
No projeto tem uma `QTextEdit` onde eu preciso colocar algumas palavras em cores diferentes.

Eu estou usando a codificação ANSI mas não está funcionando, já tentei outros módulos como colorama e colors mas nenhum funcionou, alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

O meu sistema operacional é o Windows.

O que aparece na `QTextEdit`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: E qual seria o motivo de usar ANSI em vez de HTML? Salvo engano meu, não tem nada mencionando caracteres de controle ANSI na documentação da Qt. HTML, por outro lado, tem até método próprio para  usar HTML: `setHtml()` Mais detalhes aqui: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

Comment: No projeto que mandaram eu fazer pediram para fazer com ANSI, não sei porque não querem com HTML.
Uma coisa que eu percebi é que se vc usar codificação ANSI, caracteres como '\n' por exemplo deixam de ser reconhecidos.
Além do mais essa QTextEdit vai exibir informações vindas de uma porta serial.

Comment: Vai ter que escrever um pequeno conversor então.

Comment: Como o @Bacco disse, vai ter que escrever um conversor, usando a tabela de cores entre outros e aplicar com `setFontWeight` (peso/negrito ou não), `setFontItalic`, `setUnderlineStyle`, `QTextFormat::setForeground` ... vai ter que ajustar um a um. Porque nativamente `QTextEdit` não funciona com isso.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está num porjeto 'mandado', atenha-se as especificações. Se é determinado que sejam cores "ANSI" - estas são relativas ao uso do terminal - o seu projeto provavelemtne tem que ter uma saída em terminal, e não numa janela de gráfica desenhada pelo Qt.

O Qt é um framework de muito alto nível, que entre outras coisas permite a criação de programas gráficos com rich-text, e para formatar o texto, usa as convenções do HTML e CSS. Os códigos ANSI são um quebra-galho para que terminais possam mostrar texto colorido.

VOcê tem que decidir: se tem liberdade no seu projeto para fazer em Qt em vez de terminal , também tem, naturalmente, liberdade para colorir o texto de outras formas que não código ANSI. Se não tem essa liberdade (por exemplo, se for um trabalho de escola), certamente não pode mudar o projeto do terminal para um programa em Qt. (Se não por outro motivo, justamente por que em Qt os códigos ANSI não funcionam e não tem qualquer significado).

Perceba que além das cores que podem ser um auxiliar na visualização há outros fatores que poderiam requerer que a saída do programa seja no terminal: no terminal, por padrão, a saída padrão pode ser redirecionada para um arquivo ou como entrada de outro programa -  e nesses casos, é importante que o seu projeto em Qt seja compatível com isso.

(Lembrando que você pode usar o atributo de  tag "style" inline para colocar a cor que quiser no seu texto dentro de um QTextWidget:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.show()
t = QtGui.QTextEdit('', w)
t.show()
t.append("teste")
t.append("<b>negrito</b>b")
t.append("<b style='color:red'>negrito vermelho</b>b")
```

Comment: Obrigado jsbueno, eu conversei com o pessoal e eles resolveram usar tags HTML mesmo.
Eu só queria perguntar uma coisa a vc (só curiosidade).
A única forma de colorir textos em uma QTextEdit é usando HTML ?

Comment: Sim. Por que mais de uma forma,q uando html com style inline - ou mesmo separado, é muito mais completo e flexível?  Por exemplo: códigos ANSI tem só 8 cores possíveis - com um código arbitrário para cada cor quando usado como cor de frente, e outro código arbitrário quando usado como cor de fundo.  Com a notação de cores de HTML e a facilidade de manipulação de strigns do Python, você consegue fazer uma palavra em degradê com uma linha de código, se quiser:

Comment: `texto = u"HTML é muito mais flexível para estilos de texto"`
`t.append(u''.join(u'<span style="color:#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}">{}</span>'.format(int(255.0 * i /len(texto))  ,0, int(255 - 255.0 * i/len(texto)), letra) for i, letra in enumerate(texto) ))`